# Server 2012 on Poweredge 2850

Tags: drivers, windows-server-2012, dell-poweredge

I am trying to install Windows Server 2012 onto a Dell Poweredge 2850. I have configured the RAID array and there is a logical disk showing in the PERC 4/DC raid controller interface.

Once I get to the disk selection part of the Windows set up process I am told there are no available disks. This appears to be because I need to load some drivers. I am unable to find them, however.

I can only find Server 2008 R2 drivers, which to be honest is expected but I was wondering if anyone knew if it was even possible or if anyone had attempted this previously?

I'm not particularly au fait with drivers etc so any help or pointing in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: The only way I have seen this work, is a Windows 2008 R2 > Windows Server 2012 upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

In attempting to resurrect a Win 7 system on a Dell system, I found the same thing happened to me.

Apparently the PERC drivers are not installed on the standard Windows releases and need to be obtained from the Dell website.

After contacting Dell support and being provided the driver. I installed the PERC driver I needed at the start of the installation process and things proceeded normally.

Thus, see the Dell website and get the appropriate drivers for your PERC card is the answer.  If you don't see it contact Dell directly to get their driver for the 2850.

Comment: +1. Note though that there is no need to call, dell ha a decent support website. You can find anything there.

Answer (score 2):

The driver entitled `perc-w2k3-6.46.3.64-A01.exe` found [here](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/driverdetails?driverid=KDYKD) allows you to install Windows Server 2012 directly onto a configured RAID array on a PE 2850. Tested with a PERC 4/DC but there are many drivers for other controllers included in the download.